# I got an error when I try to connect my docker via HTTPs: x509: certificate is valid for 0.0.0.0, not <My Container IP>

Tags: docker, ssl, https, openssl, tls1.2

My dockerd(docker daemon) running on my remote computer instance.

I need connect my dockerd with my local computer, and I try [This Link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#use-tls-https-to-protect-the-docker-daemon-socket)

when I finished, I got an error.

```
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=cert.pem --tlskey=key.pem -H=$HOST:2376 ps
error during connect: Get https://$HOST:2376/v1.24/containers/json: x509: certificate is valid for 0.0.0.0, not $HOST
```

What should I do?

---

Update:
`$HOST` is my remote server IP address.

Comment: If covering of some sensitive data is needed in the snippets, don't parameterise it (like with `$HOST` here, just replace it with some valid imaginary data, like `foobar.local` for your example. Otherwise there could be options in reasoning: was the provided command called as-is (with single-quotes) so `$HOST` got into the error message as-is?

Comment: I'd highly recommend turning off the remote Docker API entirely.  It's dangerous (if you can access the socket successfully, you can root the host), and practically you probably need normal login access anyways (`-v` bind-mount options always use the system the daemon is running on, so you need to `scp` files to the target system in most practical cases).

Comment: @AleksandrVinokurov Sorry, I'm new here. As you said, I did that to protect sensitive data.  `$HOST` is my remote server IP address(like 22.22.22.22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow this from the link you mentioned?

> Since TLS connections can be made through IP address as well as DNS name, the IP addresses need to be specified when creating the certificate. For example, to allow connections using 10.10.10.20 and 127.0.0.1:

```
$ echo subjectAltName = DNS:$HOST,IP:10.10.10.20,IP:127.0.0.1 >> extfile.cnf
```

Could it be that your real value (instead of the `$HOST` in *your* snippet) was not used in the aforementioned step?

Comment: I checked my cmd history, I did with `echo subjectAltName = IP:0.0.0.0 >> extfile.conf`

Comment: So, should I completely regenerate a certificate? :(

Comment: I regenerated a `server-cert.pem`. It has been solved. Thank you :)